# PostgreSQL logical replication using pglogical

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.5

I am testing logical replication using Pglogical with Postgresql v9.5.

Simple configuration seems OK.
It means:

- create pglogical extension in the two nodes
- create a set and add tables from public schema into this set,
- create a node and create a subscription in the other server.

But, subscription to a new replication_set containing tables from a specific schema does not work.

This command passed (in the provider node):

```
select pglogical.replication_set_add_all_tables(
set_name := 'new_replication_set',
schema_names := '{myschema}',
synchronize_data := 'true'
);
```

This command passed (in the subscriber node):

```
select pglogical.create_subscription(
subscription_name := 'subscription',
replication_sets := array['new_replication_set'],
provider_dsn := 'host=10.20.30.40 port=6432 dbname=production user=pglogical_prod',
synchronize_data := 'true'
);
```

**But tables in the subscriber node are empty.**

I missed something?
Thanks and regards.

**Additional information:**

- `select pglogical.alter_subscription_synchronize(...)` and `select pglogical.alter_subscription_resynchronize_table(...)` commands were sent,
- Tables in the subscriber node are in a specific schema too,
- `select * from pglogical.queue;` request is not empty.

Hereunder the log messages taken from the subscriber node :

I set log_min_message = debug5 in the subscriber node.

And hereunder the error message :

```
792 < 2018-03-14 11:38:56.449 CET >LOG:  starting apply for subscription subscription
793 < 2018-03-14 11:38:56.449 CET >DEBUG:  StartTransaction
794 < 2018-03-14 11:38:56.449 CET >DEBUG:  name: unnamed; blockState:       DEFAULT; state: INPROGR, xid/subid/cid: 0/1    /0, nestlvl: 1, children:
795 < 2018-03-14 11:38:56.449 CET >DEBUG:  CommitTransaction
796 < 2018-03-14 11:38:56.449 CET >DEBUG:  name: unnamed; blockState:       STARTED; state: INPROGR, xid/subid/cid: 0/1    /0, nestlvl: 1, children:
797 < 2018-03-14 11:38:56.449 CET >ERROR:  subscriber subscription initialization failed during nonrecoverable step (d)    , please try the setup again
798 < 2018-03-14 11:38:56.449 CET >DEBUG:  shmem_exit(1): 2 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
799 < 2018-03-14 11:38:56.449 CET >LOG:  apply worker [16870] at slot 1 generation 4 exiting with error
800 < 2018-03-14 11:38:56.449 CET >DEBUG:  shmem_exit(1): 6 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
801 < 2018-03-14 11:38:56.449 CET >DEBUG:  proc_exit(1): 2 callbacks to make
802 < 2018-03-14 11:38:56.449 CET >DEBUG:  exit(1)
803 < 2018-03-14 11:38:56.449 CET >DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
804 < 2018-03-14 11:38:56.449 CET >DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
805 < 2018-03-14 11:38:56.449 CET >DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
806 < 2018-03-14 11:38:56.450 CET >DEBUG:  reaping dead processes
807 < 2018-03-14 11:38:56.450 CET >LOG:  worker process: pglogical apply 16385:2875150205 (PID 16870) exited with exit     code 1
```

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables and schema names in the subscriber node have to be the same as the provider node.
Hereunder the error messages if the names are differents between the two nodes:

```
>LOG:  starting apply for subscription subscription
>INFO:  initializing subscriber subscription
>INFO:  synchronizing data
>ERROR:  schema "myschema" does not exist

>LOG:  starting apply for subscription subscription
>INFO:  initializing subscriber subscription
>INFO:  synchronizing data
>ERROR:  relation "myschema.tblprod2" does not exist
```

Now replication working.